# Firefox HSBC & HMRC redirect Issue

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to migrate from `Chrome` on Windows 10 to `Firefox`.

However I have noticed on two websites: www.hsbc.co.uk and www.hmrc.gov.uk (while doing a tax return) it looks like a redirect URL isn't working and just goes nowhere.

For HSBC is it when logging into online banking. To reproduce click on https://www.services.online-banking.hsbc.co.uk/gpib/group/gpib/cmn/layouts/default.html?uid=dashboard

I am seeing this issue in Ingognito mode also.

Does anyone know the issue or workaround for this as I really want to stick with Firefox.

Comment: Do you have any extensions or anything that could be blocking this? I am able to reach https://www.hsbc.co.uk/ fine and the second link redirects me to https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/hm-revenue-customs fine on Firefox

Comment: The issue is specifically around redirects when doing something secure I believe. The HSBC issue is easy to reproduce: try clicking on the Online Banking login: https://www.services.online-banking.hsbc.co.uk/gpib/group/gpib/cmn/layouts/default.html?uid=dashboard - it just hangs. HMRC is a bit difficult as I was logged in doing my tax return so can't reproduce but it was doing a similar secure redirect.

Answer (score 0):

So I missed the obvious step in the debugging checklist.

I restarted in Safe mode and by disabling the addons I had I found it was https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/cookie-banner/?src=search was causing the issue.

I did a quick search for [firefox hsbc](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=firefox%20hsbc) and got plenty of results which lead me to believe it was a browser issue.